# Error on Django URL : URLconf defined in website.urls, Django tried these URL patterns

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean

I am running a django project on a ubuntu digital ocean droplet with nginx/gunicorn on my own domain. I am using a virtual environment with Django version 3.1.6 and Python 3.8.5

I am trying to follow [Corey Shafers Django tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a48xeeo5Vnk&list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p&index=2) to create a blog app and while I can reach the generic django success page on example.com I ran into the following from example.com/blog :

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    example.com/blog
Using the URLconf defined in website.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, blog, didn't match any of these.

---

My current ~/projectdir/website/urls.py (see edit at bottom):

```html
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/',admin.site.urls),
        path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

My ~/projectdir/blog/urls.py:

```html
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='blog-home'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='blog-about'),
]
```

My ~/projectdir/blog/views.py:

```html
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Blog Home</h1>')
```

---

As far as I can tell everything looks ok syntax-wise but I can't figure out why the URLconf is not seeing the blog path. I have tried reloading nginx and that didn't help.

### EDIT

I have edited /projectdir/website/urls.py to look like this:

```html
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/',admin.site.urls),
        path('blog', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

I am still getting the same 404 reponse with "The current path, blog, didn't match any of these."

Comment: I don't see any pattern that ends in `blog` though...

Comment: you did include blog to empty path and you expect to have /blog url

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not included the blog app in your base urls.py, see [this django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view).

Comment: Hey there, I have edited the website/urls.py to have path('blog/', include('blog.urls')), instead but it is still not seeing it in urlsconf

Answer (score 1):

Your virtual environment may not be enabled in Visual Studio code. Activate venv in vscode or other , then try again
you can activate venv in vscode by ctrl+shift+P -> select interpreter ->Select Interpreter path -> select your python that you want use it.

or you dont run your project in vscode and then run it

and then  /polls request after localhost:8000 to the correct address will do

Comment: Thanks enabling virtual env worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`path('', include('blog.urls'))` urls paths should written as `path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))`.

This mean `include path` not be an empty string.